# The argument of pthread_create was used in C++ — Every time the thread function get the value was the same, why?

Tags: c++, pthreads

I used pthread_create in C++, and the program runs, but in pthread function, the argument result was the same. Why? I have used pthread_mutex_lock, but it is not effective. I can't find out the reason.

The codes below:

Minimal:

```
const int MAX_THREADS = 5;
class FileCpThread
{
public:
FileCpThread(const string &src,const string & des){
srcFile = src.c_str();
desFile = des.c_str();
}
~FileCpThread(){}
startThreadCopy();

private:
static void *threadCp(void *param);
static int getFileSize(const std::string &filename);
string srcFile;
int num;
string desFile;
};
```

Complete:

```
bool FileCpThread::startThreadCopy()
{

pthread_t pid[MAX_THREADS];

pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);

for (int i = 0; i < MAX_THREADS; i++)
{
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
this->num = i;
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
pthread_create(&pid[i], NULL, threadCp, (void *)this);
}

for (int j = 0; j < MAX_THREADS; j++)
{
pthread_join(pid[j], NULL);
}

return true;
}
int FileCpThread::getFileSize(const string &filename)
{
struct stat st;
memset(&st, 0, sizeof(st));
stat(filename.c_str(), &st);
return st.st_size;
}

void *FileCpThread::threadCp(void *param)
{
FileCpThread *ft = (FileCpThread *)param;
FILE *fin = fopen(ft->srcFile.c_str(), "r+");
FILE *fout = fopen(ft->desFile.c_str(), "w+");

int size = getFileSize(ft->srcFile.c_str());
pthread_mutex_lock(&ft->mutex);
int number =  ft->num;
pthread_mutex_unlock(&ft->mutex);
cout << "number:::" << number << endl;

fseek(fin, size * (number) / MAX_THREADS, SEEK_SET);
fseek(fout, size * (number) / MAX_THREADS, SEEK_SET);

char buff[1024] = {'\0'};
int len = 0;
int total = 0;
while ((len = fread(buff, 1, sizeof(buff), fin)) > 0)
{
fwrite(buff, 1, len, fout);
total += len;

if (total > size / MAX_THREADS)
{
  break;
}
}

fclose(fin);
fclose(fout);
}
```

Verifiable:

```
bool FileCpThread::startThreadCopy()

pthread_mutex_lock(&ft->mutex);
int number =  ft->num;
pthread_mutex_unlock(&ft->mutex);
cout << "number:::" << number << endl;
```

Comment: pthread_mutex_lock(&ft->mutex); 
int number =  ft->num;
pthread_mutex_unlock(&ft->mutex);  
cout<<"number:::"<<number<<endl;     the result was the same,4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the same value in the thread function because you pass the same value to it each time.  Your code is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < MAX_THREADS; i++)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    this->num = i;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    pthread_create(&pid[i], NULL, threadCp, (void *)this);
}
```

The value of `this` does not change between iterations, so the same value is passed to `threadCp` each time it is used.

If your problem is that all the threads see the same value for `this->num`, then the problem is still that you pass the same pointer to the function each time, but you also have the indeterminacy with which the threads are scheduled, and Sod's Law dictates that the threads won't be activated until the last one is created, so they all see the same value in `this->num`.  You have to make sure that each thread gets independent information to work with — assuming each thread should be getting independent information.

---

For N threads, you need to create an array of N values — it appears that N `int` might be sufficient, and (a) set the elements appropriately and (b) pass one element of the array to each thread.

As an element of the class:

```
int thread_number[MAX_THREADS];
```

As initialization:

```
for (int i = 0; i < MAX_THREADS; i++)
    this->thread_number[i] = i;
```

In the call to `pthread_create()`:

```
pthread_create(&pid[i], NULL, threadCp, &this->thread_number[i]);
```

In the function `threadCp()`, instead of:

```
FileCpThread *ft = (FileCpThread *)param;
```

use:

```
int number = *(int *)param;
```

And you don't need the mutex for synchronization any more (at least, not to control access to the thread number).

If the number of threads is variable, use a `vector<int>`.  If it would be more sensible to compute the split of the file before launching the threads, do that (it probably is sensible).

Do note that having 5 threads accessing separate portions of a single file is probably not going to improve overall performance.  As an exercise in coordination between processes, it is fine.  As an exercise in improving overall performance, it is probably not a good idea.  (Reason: the file will be on a single file system, so the same controllers will be used in accessing the separate sections of disk, leading to head positioning contention. Performance might actually be worse than running single-threaded.)

Comment: I don't know what you want to do, so I can't tell you how to modify it.

Comment: how to modify the code to  run correctly,i mean that make sure the logic is correct

Comment: You've not stated what you're trying to do.  I can't help you until you've provided more information about what you think is the correct behaviour.  The code is fairly large; you should read up on how to create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).  I'm not convinced this code is an MCVE.

Comment: Are the five threads making five separate copies of the file, or are they combining their efforts to copy five parts of one file to another file?  If the latter, then threading is unlikely to improve performance.

Comment: yes,i want to cut the file to 5 parts,each thread to copy one part.so what is your best way to do this,one thread? i have edit my question,and show MCVE example